# Counter in Django nest for-loop

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Considering

```
<ul>
{% for l in [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e'], ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i']] %}
{% for i in l %}
<li>
...
</li>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

in a Django template, what should I replace `...` with to get

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

i.e. how can I get a counter for a nest for loop where the lenght of the elements in the external loop aren't always the same?

**Update**

```
<ul>
{% for l in [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e'], ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i']] %}
{% for i in l %}
<li>
  {{forloop.counter}}
</li>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

gives

```
1
2
3
1
2
1
2
3
4
```

and

```
<ul>
{% for l in [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e'], ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i']] %}
{% for i in l %}
<li>
  {{forloop.parentloop.counter}}
</li>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

gives

```
1
1
1
2
2
3
3
3
3
```

Comment: similar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74094611

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django template counter in nested loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870890/django-template-counter-in-nested-loops)

Answer (score 1):

For the inner loop, you can use `{{ forloop.counter }}`. Meanwhile, for the outer loop, you can use `{{ forloop.parentloop.counter }}`.

**Update**

Have you tried doing `{{ forloop.parentloop.counter|add:forloop.counter }}`?

[Source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#for)

Comment: Thanks @rod-xavier. Unfortunately `forloop.counter` and `forloop.parentloop.counter` don't solve the problem alone and since the elements of the external list don't have the same size I couldn't think a a simple algebric operation to compute the counter.

Comment: You can either merge together your lists in a view and pass that to the template, or write a simple tag to add the two indices: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags

Comment: This does *not* work. For the OP's example, it yields: `2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7`.